# Visual Studio 2019 C# Create Snipped using selected Text

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I want to create a snippet using a text selection.

Currently, my snippet looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>Debug element</Title>
      <Author>Ken Pino</Author>
      <Description>Debug log for selected element</Description>
      <Shortcut>dd</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="CSharp">
        <![CDATA[Debug.Log($$"[Debug] $Element$ is: {$Element$}");]]>
      </Code>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal>
          <ID>Element</ID>
          <ToolTip>Insert element</ToolTip>
          <Default>Element</Default>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

I want $Element$ to be replaced by the text I have selected so that if I add the snipped while the text "myVar" is selected I will see this:

```
Debug.Log($"[Debug] myVar: {myVar}");
```

TY in advance!